# Add JSON message in RestCotroller

Tags: json, rest, exceptionhandler

I want to add JSON message on REST controller class(methods). For example i have delete method look's like:

```
@DeleteMapping("/people/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<PersonDto> deletePerson(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return personService
                .deletePerson(id)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
```

I want to return message Person (maybe numer of id) deleted.
Should i use ExceptionHandler? Or Can i do this Using exceptionHnadler?

Comment: I mean that when i test this request in postman i want to recive json information.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `ResponseBean` POJO class as

```
public class ResponseBean {

    public final Long id;
    public final String msg;

    public ResponseBean(Long id, String msg) {
        this.id = id;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Change your controller method as

```
@DeleteMapping("/people/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseBean> deletePerson(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return personService
            .deletePerson(id)
            .map(dto -> new ResponseBean(dto.getId(), "Person Deleted Successfully"))
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "id" : 2,
  "msg" : "Person Deleted Successfully"
}
```

You can customize `ResponseBean` class as per your need.

Comment: I have springbootproject. Should i have create pojo class and call bean, or should i create bean in configuration springboot class?

Comment: You just need to create a POJO class (similar to `PersonDto`), no need to create in `configuration`. Also you can choose any other name you like instead of `ResponseBean`